# "COM object separated from its underlying RCW" error when using VirtualFileDataObject with async/await

Tags: com, async-await, .net-4.6

I'm trying to use David Anson's [`VirtualFileDataObject`](https://dlaa.me/blog/post/9913083) (as shipped in [this NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/VirtualFileDataObject/)), and there's a few problems I'm running into. One occurs when passing an `async void` to the `StreamContents` property. This will work fine:

```
Dim descriptor As New VirtualFileDataObject.VirtualFileDataObject.FileDescriptor With {
    .Name = info.FileName,
    .StreamContents = Sub(s)
                          Dim d As New FileTransfer.Downloader(info.BildID)
                          Dim fs = d.DownloadSingleAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()

                          fs.Position = 0

                          fs.CopyTo(s)
                      End Sub}
```

(Downloader is a class that fetches data using web services. It shouldn't be relevant, as `DownloadSingleAsync` returns a Task`Stream`.)

But of course, `GetAwaiter()` isn't how you're supposed to await something.

This, however:

```
Dim descriptor As New VirtualFileDataObject.VirtualFileDataObject.FileDescriptor With {
    .Name = info.FileName,
    .StreamContents = Async Sub(s)
                          Dim d As New FileTransfer.Downloader(info.BildID)
                          Dim fs = Await d.DownloadSingleAsync().ConfigureAwait(False)

                          fs.Position = 0

                          Await fs.CopyToAsync(s).ConfigureAwait(False)
                      End Sub}
```

…will throw a COMException.

My guess is that something is released too soon. I found [this piece of code](https://github.com/crackalak/VirtualFileDataObject/blob/master/VirtualFileDataObject/VirtualFileDataObject.cs#L384):

```
// Return an IntPtr for the IStream
ptr = Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject(iStream, typeof(IStream));
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(iStream);
```

Perhaps `ReleaseComObject` is called too soon. Is there some call I can make (perhaps similar to `GC.SuppressFinalize()`?) to prevent the COM object from being released until I'm done?

(edit) As requested, a stacktrace:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.InvalidComObjectException
  HResult=0x80131527
  Message=COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.StubRegisterRCW(Object pThis)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream.Write(Byte[] pv, Int32 cb, IntPtr pcbWritten)
   at System.IO.Stream.<>c.<BeginWriteInternal>b__46_0(Object )
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.IO.Stream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.IO.Stream.<>c.<BeginEndWriteAsync>b__53_1(Stream stream, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncTrimPromise`1.Complete(TInstance thisRef, Func`3 endMethod, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at MyApp.Bilder._Closure$__178-0.VB$StateMachine___Lambda$__0.MoveNext() in Bilder.vb:line 467
```

Comment: No, that is not likely, ConfigureAwait(false) is surely the poison-pill.  Hard to be sure without a stack trace.  Threading is not a minor detail in COM, it was designed to assume that programmers don't know how to write thread-safe code correctly.  When you make a call from a worker thread on a single-threaded object then COM itself takes care of marshaling the call back to the thread that created the object, the equivalent of Invoke() in .NET.  That can't work if the thread is not around anymore, you get this exception.

Comment: I've added a stacktrace. For whatever it's worth, the stacktrace is almost identical if I leave out `ConfigureAwait(false)`; the line instead becomes `at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()`.

Comment: You can't use `async void` lambda here. Apparently `FileDescriptor` doesn't support asynchronous writing to the stream. Your lambda returns to the caller at the point of its 1st `await`, and `FileDescriptor` expects the stream to have been fully written to at that point. It has no idea about asynchronous continuation of your lambda. If it had asynchronous support, the lambda signature would be `Func<Stream, Task>` rather than `Action<Stream>`. So, you have to make a blocking call as you do already.